# Outlook Javascript API appointment object

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook, office365, office-js

How to change the appointment busy status "show as" to out of office using javascript(Outlook web add-in) ?

How to change the value of all day event to true (tick it) using javascript(Outlook web add-in) ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the features you requested are not a part of the product. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

You can try looking into [using REST APIs from your add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api) and particularly this [update event API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/event_update). However, this will not update live on the form, so it may not suit your purpose.